# How to select all distinct property values for a property of all documents in an index

Tags: elasticsearch

Given documents in ElasticSearch v2.0.0 that look as shown below, how can I determine that the unique group names across all people are: Developers, Scrummasters, UX, Admins.

```
{
  "_index": "people",
  "_type": "employee",
  "_id": "8725",
  "_source": {
    "id": 43470,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 345,
        "name": "Developers"
      },
      {
        "id": 75432,
        "name": "Scrummasters"
      },
      {
        "id": 5789,
        "name": "UX"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_index": "people",
  "_type": "employee",
  "_id": "8726",
  "_source": {
    "id": 43471,
    "firstName": "Fred",
    "lastName": "Bloggs",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 474,
        "name": "Developers"
      },
      {
        "id": 824,
        "name": "Admins"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a use-case for [Term Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), however since `groups` field in your documents is `nested`, you need to use [Nested Term Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-aggregation.html) for finding the distinct values along with the count of their occurrences across documents.

```
"aggs" : {
        "groups" : {
            "nested" : {
                "path" : "groups"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "unique" : { "terms" : { "field" : "groups.name" } }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you break this down for me, as I'm reading the official docs, and not quite groking it.

Comment: What part of it are you not able to understand? Are you aware of the concept of aggregation, terms aggregation, nested documents, then it should be easy to understand